# Find a particular solution that satisfies the initial condition $yy' - 2e^x = 0$

Tags: calculus

> This is actually the second part of a larger question:
>
> The given information is: $$y'= x/\left(x^2 + 1\right)$$
> I have calculated this from the first part of the question:$$y = \ln\left(x^2 + 1\right)/2 + C$$
> The second part is "Find a particular solution that satisfies the initial condition:" $$yy' - 2e^x = 0$$
> I have been going around in confusing loop about how to solve this problem which is pretty hard to type down. I just cant seem to find $C$'s value.

Comment: At least learn to typeset in Latex before asking! Your question will be much more clear! :)

Comment: @ale42 Thx will do

Comment: What you have written above is not an initial condition, but another differential equation (there are two differential equations in your question). Please correct your post if you want to get answers.

Comment: @AlexM. that is why i am confused, the question was given like this

Comment: @AlexM. it actually had two parts, the first part I was told to find y from y' which I got. the second part was "Find a particular solution that satisfies the initial condition yy′ − 2e^x = 0".

Comment: Then the original statement is mistaken. It simply makes no mathematical sense.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks, I have been on this for hours thinking that I have missed something important...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is $yy'=2e^{x}$, so  $\frac{1}{2}(y^{2})'=2e^{x}$ so $(y^{2})'=4e^{x}$ so $y^{2}=4e^{x}+C$.

Answer (score 0):

write it as a first order differential equation for $u = y^2.$  you have $$  u' = 2yy' = 4e^x\tag 1$$ look for a particular solution of $(1)$ in the form $$ u = ae^x\to a = 4$$ and the homogenous solution is $$u = c $$  you have then $$ u = c + 4e^x, y = \pm \sqrt{4e^x + c}.$$

Comment: Your answer here [ended up in the Low Quality review queue](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/423841). I'm not entirely sure why, but a possible reason is that it was automatically flagged by the system for, among other things, the lack of capitalization. I've noticed that this is a running theme in your posting history. Please consider properly capitalizing and punctuating your posts in the future. Posting is not a race (not that disregarding the shift key even saves that much time).

Comment: @epimorphic, thanks.  punctuation, i can see why; not capitalization. it is not save time that i don't capitalize; i just don't like it.